# Link_to to the same page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on Rails, I appreciate your guidance.

I have below line in my show.html.haml. Right now, when I click on a link that I have created in show page, it loads a new page which directs to conversation_messages_path. Instead of loading a new page I want to see this page in one of my columns in show.html.haml page which Link_to is part of it. Something like partial!

```
= link_to (conversation.messages.last.body),conversation_messages_path(conversation),class: "last-message"
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Its very unclear what "send a page" is supposed to mean or what you mean by "see conversation_messages_path page in a column in the same page(show.html.haml)". It sounds somewhat like you're asking about AJAX which is the topic for an entire book [or guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) and not a Stackoverflow answer. It could also be [partials](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)... Please respond by editing your question to add clarity and not by commenting.

Comment: @max I updated my post, I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Does this code get your idea?

```
config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "/home", to: "pages#home"
  root to: "pages#show"
end

app/views/pages/show.html.haml
= link_to "Message from this page. Click to go!", root_path(params.permit(:flag).merge(:flag => true))
- if @flagCount
  %form{ :action => "/save", :method => "post" }
    %fieldset
      %label{:for => "title"} This is #{@indexCount} time:
      %input{:name => "title", :type => "text", :value => ""}/
      %input{:type => "submit" }
- else
  Nothing. This is #{@indexCount} time.
%p This line is variables information: @flagCount = #{@flagCount}; @indexCount = #{@indexCount}

app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  # before_action :accept_all_params
  @@staticCount = 1
  @@staticFlag = false
  def home
  end

  def show
    if params[:flag].present?
      @@staticFlag = ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(params[:flag])
      if @@staticFlag
        @@staticCount = @@staticCount + 1
      else
        @@staticCount = 1
        @@staticFlag = false
      end
    else
      @@staticCount = 1
      @@staticFlag = false
    end
    @indexCount = @@staticCount
    @flagCount = @@staticFlag
  end

  private
  # permit all parameters
  # def accept_all_params
  #   params.permit!
  # end

end
```

Way to run: Go to root_path: `127.0.0.1:3000`, then click to link_to part, it will reload page with show count up times click on the link.

All things is easy to understand, and note the line `params.permit(:flag).merge(:flag => true)` permit variable flag before send its value to server.

Happy coding! : D